# Blazor Server Content-Security-Policy For External Libraries

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

I am trying to add Content-Security-Policy to my Blazor Server website.  I do this by adding this to Startup.cs,  in Configure method:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");               
  context.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
  context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
  context.Response.Headers.Add(
       "Content-Security-Policy",
       "base-uri 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=='; " +
       "block-all-mixed-content;" +
       "default-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=='" +
       "img-src data: https:; " +
       "script-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=='; " +                    
       "style-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g==';" +
       "font-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g==';" +
       "upgrade-insecure-requests;" +
       "connect-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g==';");
    await next();   });
```

But the problem I am facing is that some libraries I use (which I include locally in the project) throws errors.  For example, fontawesome/all.js throws an error saying

> "all.js:2626 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> 'nonce-rAnd0m'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-ixVUGs3ai0rMA0pgIVBN0KVlYbQip7/5SGmnUwJPNqE='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I added a nonce to the file links, in _Host.cshtml like this:

```
<link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" nonce="8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g==" />
<script src="~/lib/font-awesome/js/all.js" nonce="8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=="></script>
```

but this still causes an error.  How can I continue to use these libraries, without relaxing the security policy?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that, when the page renders, the links to my libraries get the nonce stripped out, like this:

```
<script src="/lib/font-awesome/js/all.js" nonce></script>
```

**EDIT**

I also found that if I remove  `"default-src 'self' 'nonce-8IBTHwOdqNKAWeKl7plt8g=='"` I no longer get any errors. But, the nonce seems to make no difference.  I can have nonces that don't match the style/js links and they all still work, so I am not sure what the point of the nonce is?